# Geometry Nodes : boolean operation on a collection

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

first time user, hope I'll lay out my problem properly !

I'm trying to build a personnalized geometry node to generate outlines and edges on collection of objects, the goal is to create nice looking 3D scenes to use in my storyboard (I'm a board artist, I like to play with blender).

Outlines and edges, it's simple but I achieved that, wasn't hard : [image]

I'll try to refine that later.

My problem comes when I want to draw lines on intersecting objects, and I want to be able to apply that to a collection of objects. I wanted to use the boolean node to do that, it works when I inject specified meshes :[image]

But when I try to work with a collection containing the exact same objects, I read that I needed the collection info node and the realize instance one... but it doesn't work, no matter what I try the union doesn't work :[image]

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you try the union doesn't work? Try this: delete the *Realize Instances* node. You do not even have to use *Separate Children* or *Relative*.

[image: boolean on collection instance]

Comment: It works perfectly... my mistake was trying that in Blender 4.1, I don't know what changed in those nodes but I had to come back to 3.6.1. A shame, I hoped to use 4.0 method of saving geometry nodes as assets.

Comment: @jep2k3 I see, wasn't obvious from your question that it's 4.1, and we usually consider questions about alpha or beta versions etc. to be off-topic here, since features (and probable bugs) are still in development and might be subject to change before being officially released as a stable version.

Comment: Yeah sure, no problem, it's my mistake ^^ I'm fiddling around in 4.1, but at least if I have a geometry node working in 3.6, I'd be more than happy (and I'm getting there ^^). Thank you again !